# Performing a where clause within a foreach loop when using jQuery Templates

Tags: jquery, foreach, where-clause, jquery-templates

I'm using a jQuery Template as part of a project at work and was wondering whether it was possible to use a "Where" clause within the {{each}} loop.

For example:

```
{{each ChildProduct where ChildProduct.ParentID === $index}}
```

Or is my only option to use a conditional statement within the loop?